# Trigger a Lambda function from multiple S3 file uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to some AWS services.

Our source team uploads 2 files in a S3 bucket at some interval. They run one pipeline and upload a file in S3. Then they run another process and upload another file in S3. Both their processes run in parallel so files are not uploaded in a specific order.

we need to trigger our Lambda function when both files are uploaded in S3.
We tried to trigger lambda from S3 events and SNS but it trigger lambda twice because of 2 S3 events.

What is the best approach to handle this? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Not possible using S3 natively - pass them to SQS & have a Lambda which wakes up after the intervals to check to see if you have 2 messages in there or if there are messages in the queue with the 2 filenames that you need

Comment: How should the Lambda function know when to run? Do the objects always have the same name, so it should specifically look for both of the objects? Or perhaps it should run whenever there are two objects in a particular bucket Prefix? Basically, how can you better define "when both files are uploaded"?

Comment: One option could be to trigger lambda function on s3 create event using s3 event notifications. Lambda function then implement the logic to check if both files are present or not and proceed accordingly